# ServiceStack Validation RuleSet for Post is not working

Tags: validation, servicestack

i use `ServiceStack` build a web service,

this is my `validator` code:

```
public class AccountValidator : AbstractValidator<AccountModel>
{

    public AccountValidator()
    {

        //only for post 
        RuleSet(ServiceStack.ApplyTo.Post, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(s => s.Password).Length(30);
        });
    }
}
```

**Service code**

```
public object Post(Account req) {
        AccountModel model = req.ConvertTo<AccountModel>();

        var result = this.Validator.Validate(model);
        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            //is aways true
        }
        throw result.ToException();
    }
```

the Account.Password is "abc" ,way the `result.IsValid` is `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is always `true` because the `ApplyTo.Post` condition in your validator **only applies to rules that are validated on the Request DTO**. The `ApplyTo` conditions don't work for FluentValidation that is invoked manually. See the [Validation Documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#wiki-fluentvalidation-for-request-dtos).

But given that you are converting the `Account` into an `AccountModel` you could use the `ValidationFeature` plugin to check the validation of `Account` before converting it to an `AccountModel`.

Thus:

```cs
public class AccountValidator : AbstractValidator<Account>
{
    public AccountValidator()
    {
        RuleSet(ApplyTo.Post, () => RuleFor(s => s.Password).Length(30));
    }
}

// Account will be validated on POST
public object Post(Account req)
{
    // Account is valid coming into the request
    AccountModel model = req.ConvertTo<AccountModel>();

    // Is it not safe to assume the model is valid, because Account is valid?
}
```